# stop Sticky service that uses handler inside

Tags: android, background-process

I'm creating a service that keeps showing a toast for how long it is running. I want to make it exist even after app is destroyed.
For showing how long it is running I am using a handler. But with `stopService()` method call I can not stop it. Also if I remove callbacks on `onDestroy()` of the service it stops showing toast after first one is shown. So I need a way to stop the service without removing callbacks on `onDestroy()`, or is there other way to keep showing toast messages?

heres the activity related code:

```
Intent intent;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_status);

    intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);

//OnButton.setOnclickListener() - > StartLogging();
//StopButton.setOnclickListener() - > StopLogging();

}

private void StartLogging() {
    startService(intent);
}

void stopLogging() {
    stopService(intent);
}
```

on service:

```
    public MyService() {
    }

    Handler handler;
    Runnable r;
    static int i;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        handler = new Handler();
        onTaskRemoved(intent);
        stopSelf();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is a Service running in Background",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startLogging();
        return START_STICKY; // I tried return START_NOT_STICKY; as well but the service is not stopping on button click/handler keeps posting message if not removed callbacks from onDestroy(), but if did then it shows toasts once.
    }

    private void startLogging() {

        r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                i++;

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "running in Background for  "+(i*5),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(r, 5000);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
         
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "It is removed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "It is destroyed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//        handler.removeCallbacks(r);

        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

It does not stop service after calling with `stopService()`.
Please suggest me how can I stop this service at the button click listener `stopLogging()` method and also keep showing the toasts before I press the button?

Comment: You can not keep alive Service with `Handler`. `Handler` has nothing to do with Service .. You probably need to give a thought on the solution to your problem.  Because your service will destroy in background that's the way it is now ..

Comment: I'm less worried about if it will stay alive. Currently I am focusing on starting and stopping that service while handler posts toasts till the service is terminated. I need suggestion on other way of keeping a looping method on a service.

Comment: The only way to do it is to use a Foreground Service And you do not need to show toast because foreground service Shows a non cancelable notification in tray..

Comment: Workmanager can be a solution?

Comment: NO Workmanager serves a different purpose ..